# ¿Cómo puedo asignar una ID automática a cada objeto del ArrayList?

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

Quería crear un ArrayList en el cual, al pintarlo sobre pantalla, aparezca un número automático el cual indica la posición de cada objeto. Es decir, cuando se cree un nuevo objeto, su ID será un número mayor que el anterior, y así continuamente.

```
public class ListaAlumnos {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

ArrayList <Alumno> listaAlumnos = new ArrayList<Alumno>();  


public void AñadirAlumno () {
    
    
    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del alumno: ");
    String nombre = sc.nextLine();
  
    System.out.println("Introduzca el apellido del alumno: ");
    String apellido = sc.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Introduzca el grupo del alumno: ");
    int grupo = sc.nextInt();

    listaAlumnos.add(new Alumno(nombre, apellido, grupo));

}
```

Comment: Puedes mirar la ID del último elemento añadido (posición `listaAlumnos.size() -1`)y sumarle uno. Puedes usar 1 cuando la lista está vacía

Comment: ¿quieres mostrar la posición de cada objeto cuando imprimes la lista.?  O generar un **ID** único para cada objeto creado, aunque no esté en una lista?

Comment: Si, quiero mostrar la posicion de cada objeto

Answer (score 0):

Para presentar la lista simplemente haces un método que imprima cada alumno de tu ArrayList, tomando en cuenta que todos ellos tienen un índice por defecto (recuerda que comienza en cero). O sea, algo como:

```
public void imprimirLista(){
    for(int i=0; i<this.listaAlumnos.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("Alumno[" + (i+1) + "]:" + this.listaAlumnos.get(i));
        //Nótese que se usa (i+1) para que la cuenta sea "natural" a partir de 1
    }
}
```

Para que funcione sin problemas, sería necesario que tengas el toString() en tu clase Alumno...
Si por otro lado requieres guardar el id explícitamente en el objeto alumno, simplemente pasa como argumento this.listaAlumnos.size(), ya que tiene el número de objetos de la lista...